# I can't re add google account after factory reset , edited host & after clear cache and data. Pls help

Tags: google

i changed my simcard last month and since then i have noticed that i can't log in to my google account, gmail and also instagram. Play store always stopped as well.

1. I tried some of the solutions provided on youtube like editing host (my host is already 127.0.0.1 local host), i dont know whether i should change it or just remain it like that coz some said delete everything and type host (127.0.0.1 local host) and some need to add the # (but i don't have the other line).
2. I've already clear cache & data, force stop Play store, Google play services, Google Framework, Google account manager &  remove google acc (my account already unable 2 steps verification) then tried to re add again but failed.
3. I've already factory reset my phone as well and try to re add google account but still failed. Now im using application which I downloaded thru apkmirror.com.(play store didnt work). I really appreciate anyone experts could help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have SIM locking on before you switched the SIM card?

Comment: im not sure about that how do i check it?

Comment: I'm not sure if you'd be able to. It's a safety system that locks down the phone when the SIM is changed, I.e phone is stolen. It would cause problems very similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I tried doing the same on a high speed WiFi and it worked out for me.. meanwhile if this doesn't fix you can take important backups and try:

- flashing your phone with its stock ROM
- switching to a WiFi network or try the same with another SIM card
- make it *localhost* rather than *local host* in the host file (as described by you)

Comment: ok i will try it tq